# Experience replay memory

Tags: julia

I have just begun learning Julia. Here is an implementation of experience replay memory for use in a reinforcement learning algorithm. It is pretty simple, essentially a ring buffer with the following requirements:

- Used to store 1D arrays of numbers, typically Float32 or Float64. All the stored arrays are the same size.
- Has a maximum capacity, after which new entries overwrite old ones
- Has a sample function for retrieving a given number of entries

```
import Base.length

struct Memory{T <: Real}
   max_size::UInt32
   experiences::Vector{Vector{T}}
end

Memory{T}(max_size) where {T <: Real} = Memory{T}(max_size, Vector{Vector{T}}())

length(memory::Memory) = length(memory.experiences)

function remember!(memory::Memory, experience)
   size = length(memory)
   if size == memory.max_size
      memory.experiences[1 + size % memory.max_size] = experience
   else
      push!(memory.experiences, experience)
   end
end

function sample(memory::Memory{T}, count::Integer) where {T <: Real}
   size = length(memory)
   @assert count <= size
   return [memory.experiences[1 + rand(UInt32) % size] for i in 1:count]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

- There's a [`CircularBuffer`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/DataStructures.jl/blob/master/src/circular_buffer.jl) type in `DataStructures`, which does pretty much the same.  Have a look at its code for some inspiration.  Or reuse it, if it fits your needs and you don't hesitate to add that dependency.
- Regarding the point before, I'd especially recommend to implement the common interfaces, and probably `iterate` as well.  `remember!` makes sense semantically, but `push!` is the standard name for this functionality.  You could implement `remember!` in terms of `push!` and export both, or just use `push!` and mention it in the docs.
- There isn't really a need to be so specific about types.  I'd just use

  ```
  struct Memory{T}
     max_size::UInt32
     experiences::Vector{T}
  end
  ```

  Nothing is lost by generalizing in this way, since you never use information about the content.  But who knows, maybe you later want switch to different types for experiences, eg. `StaticVector`s.
- I would doubt whether using `UInt32` saves more than it complicates.  `Int` is pretty much standard for everything of this kind: lengths, indices, offsets, etc.
- Depending on the sizes of your use case, it might be better to preallocate `experiences` as `Vector{T}(undef, max_size)` and use just indexing (and keeping track of the actual length), instead of `push!`ing until full -- see the `DataStructures` implementation.  If not, calling `sizehint!(experiences, max_size)` might be good, if you expect to always exhaust the full capacity.
- Instead of providing `sample`, I'd recommend [hooking into `rand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/stdlib/Random/#Hooking-into-the-Random-API-1), thereby getting more methods for free.  In the simplest case, this just consists of defining

  ```
  Random.rand(rng::Random.AbstractRNG, s::Random.SamplerTrivial{Memory{T}}) where {T} = rand(rng, s[].experiences)
  ```

  which gives you all variations: `rand(m)`, `rand(m, N)` (corresponging to your `sample`), `rand(rng, m)`,  etc.  Especially the form with a provided RNG is relevant if you want to write reproducible experiments.  The `rand!` methods seem not to work by default, but can be added easily if you need them.  (If you switch to a preallocation + indexing solution, you need to make sure to sample only from `@view experiences[1:length]`.)

  And note that you can directly sample from an array `a` using `rand(a)`.